# Animated TV show on VHS about winged people with powers solving problems

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I don’t remember the name of it, but I remember it was animated and I had it on VHS. I watched it when I was little so that would have been 2003 but it was my sister’s tape and she was born in 1993.

It was about people, and each of them had a special power and a different colour. They also ALL had wings (I think four), and they would solve different problems with their powers! I feel like I remember one of them being pink and it had a blonde man in it.

Comment: Powerpuff girls? Power Rangers?

Comment: Do you remember at all if there was a Native American character?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Flyz I never  watched this show, but I do know they all had wings and were color themed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes me think of *[Battle of the Planets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Planets)* (1978-1980), adapted from the Japanese anime [Gatchaman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Ninja_Team_Gatchaman).  There have been lots of cartoon featuring teams of colorful heroes, but the wings are quite a bit more distinctive.

The basic scenario, per Wikipedia

> Battle of the Planets cast five young people as G-Force, consisting of Mark, Jason, Princess, Keyop, and Tiny. G-Force protects Earth from the planet Spectra and other attacks from beyond space. The most prominent field commander of the Spectra forces was a villainous, masked individual known as Zoltar. Zoltar would receive his orders directly from a being he would refer to as the "Luminous One". The Luminous One would appear as a ghost-like, disembodied, floating head. Who, or what, this being actually was, is never explained in any detail throughout the series.
>
> The main ship of the G-Force team was called the Phoenix, which could carry, transport, and deploy four smaller vehicles, each operated by one team member. The four vehicles included a futuristic race car with various hidden weapons driven by Jason; this vehicle was concealed within the Phoenix's nosecone. The "galacti-cycle", a futuristic motor cycle Princess rode, was stored within the left wing capsule of the Phoenix. Keyop's "Space Bubble", an all-terrain, tank-like vehicle capable of VTOL as well as being a submersible craft, was held in the right storage capsule of the Phoenix. And lastly, a futuristic jet fighter Mark pilots was stored in the top rear section of the Phoenix command island structure, and which used its tail fin to make up the center tail fin of the Phoenix. The fifth crew member, Tiny, was assigned to pilot the Phoenix rather than one of the detachable craft.
>
> A regularly featured plot device was the transformation of the Phoenix into a flaming bird-shaped craft able to handle virtually any exceptional situation by functioning as a sort of giant, super blowtorch called the Fiery Phoenix. The Phoenix's primary weapon was a supply of rockets called "TBX missiles" in the series. It also occasionally flaunted a powerful solar-powered energy blaster, although the team had the misfortune of choosing very cloudy days to use it.
>
> The G-Force team themselves would use a combination of martial arts skill, ninja-like weapons, and their "cerebonic" powers to dispatch hordes of enemy soldiers and overcome other obstacles. Their bird-like costumes include wing-like capes that could fan out and function nearly identically to parachutes and/or wing suits, enabling the G-Force members to drift or glide down to safety from heights which would otherwise prove fatal.

Comment: It's worth noting that the series was marketed in the US exclusively as "G-Force"

Answer (score 0):

It might be [*SilverHawks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilverHawks), an American animated television series developed by Rankin/Bass Productions and distributed by Lorimar-Telepictures in 1986.

[image: Title image for SilverHawks]

> A bionic policeman called Commander Stargazer recruited the SilverHawks, heroes who are "partly metal, partly real," to fight the evil Mon*Star, an escaped alien mob boss who transforms into an enormous armor-plated creature with the help of Limbo's Moonstar. Joining Mon*Star in his villainy is an intergalactic mob: the snakelike Yes-Man, the blade-armed Buzz-Saw, the "bull"-headed Mumbo-Jumbo, a weather controller called Windhammer, a shapeshifter known as Mo-Lec-U-Lar, a robotic card shark called Poker-Face, the weapons-heavy Hardware, and "the musical madness of" Melodia who uses a "keytar" that fires musical notes.
>
> Quicksilver (formerly Jonathan Quick) leads the SilverHawks, with his metal bird companion Tally-Hawk at his side. Twins Emily and Will Hart became Steelheart and Steelwill, the SilverHawks's technician and strongman respectively. Country-singing Bluegrass piloted the team's ship, the Maraj (pronounced "mirage" on the series, but given that spelling on the Kenner toy). Rounding out the group is a youngster "from the planet of the mimes," named "The Copper Kidd" and usually called "Kidd" for short, a mathematical genius who spoke in whistles and computerized tones. Their bionic bodies are covered by a full-body close-fitting metal armor that only exposes the face and an arm, the armor is equipped with a retractile protective mask, retractable under-arm wings (except Bluegrass), thrusters on their heels, and laser-weapons in their shoulders.

### Theme song and Opening